# Reading numeric data from a text file to one column vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have a text file `a.text` of the form

```
    2    3    4    
    1    5    6
```

Now,  I want to read this text file using Matlab and make a column vector `b` of the form :

```
b =

     2
     3
     4
     1
     5
     6
```

The original text file contains `100*100` numbers. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [textread](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textread.html)

```
b = textread('a.txt','%d');
```